# Make function of list of tuples extremely efficient in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, optimization, tuples

I have made a helper function named `get_document_topics_for_corpus` to get list of tuples. However, it's not very efficient. The way it's called is as follows:

```
topics = lda.get_document_topics(corpus, per_word_topics=True)
doc_topics, word_topics, word_phis = get_document_topics_for_corpus(topics)

print "Document topics: ", doc_topics
print "Word topics: ", word_topics
print "Word phis:", word_phis
```

And, the result returned is this:

```
Document topics:  [(96, 0.75250000000000006), (34, 0.80200000000000227), (70, 0.80200000000000093), (60, 0.75250000000000161), (80, 0.85857142857136792), (58, 0.7525000000000015), (91, 0.75250000000000017), (28, 0.50499999999999268), (62, 0.66999998118978443)]

Word topics:  [(0, [96, 70]), (1, [96, 80]), (2, [96, 34]), (3, [80, 58]), (4, [80, 58]), (5, [80, 91]), (6, [80, 70, 34]), (7, [80, 70, 58]), (8, [70, 34]), (9, [28, 62, 60]), (10, [62, 60, 91]), (11, [60, 91])]

Word phis: [(0, [(96, 0.99999999999999989), (70, 0.99999999999999989)]), (1, [(96, 0.99999999999999989), (80, 1.0)]), (2, [(96, 0.99999999999999989), (34, 1.0)]), (3, [(80, 1.0), (58, 1.0)]), (4, [(80, 1.0), (58, 1.0000000000000002)]), (5, [(80, 1.0), (91, 1.0)]), (6, [(80, 1.0), (70, 1.0), (34, 2.0)]), (7, [(80, 1.0), (70, 1.0), (58, 1.0000000000000002)]), (8, [(70, 1.0), (34, 1.0)]), (9, [(28, 1.0), (62, 1.0), (60, 1.0)]), (10, [(62, 1.0), (60, 1.0), (91, 0.99999999999999989)]), (11, [(60, 1.0), (91, 1.0)])]
```

I have written the helper function for doing this task as follows:

```
def get_document_topics_for_corpus(topics):
    document_topics = dict()
    word_topics = dict()
    word_phis = dict()

    doc_topics = list()
    word_top = list()
    word_ph = list()

    for doc_topic, word_topic, word_phi in topics:

        #Document_topics aggregation
        key_doc = doc_topic[0][0]
        value_doc = doc_topic[0][1]
        document_topics.setdefault(key_doc, value_doc)

        #Word_topics aggregation
        for key in  word_topic:
            word_topics.setdefault(key[0], [])
            word_topics[key[0]].append(key_doc)

        #Word_phis aggregation
        for key in word_phi:
            word_phis.setdefault(key[0], [])
            word_phis[key[0]].append(key[1][0])

    for key, value in document_topics.iteritems():
        temp = (key, value)
        doc_topics.append(temp)

    for key, value in word_topics.iteritems():
        temp = (key, value)
        word_top.append(temp)

    for key, value in word_phis.iteritems():
        temp = (key, value)
        word_ph.append(temp)


    return (doc_topics, word_top, word_ph)
```

I am aggregating this result from list of topics where each topic is a tuple consisting of document topics, word topics and word_phis. In order to understand that, the topics look like follows, where each topic is separated by '-------'

```
new doc
Document topics: [(79, 0.75250000000000072)]
Word topics: [(0, [79]), (1, [79]), (2, [79])]
Word phis: [(0, [(79, 1.0)]), (1, [(79, 1.0)]), (2, [(79, 1.0)])]
--------------
new doc
Document topics: [(23, 0.85857142857143054)]
Word topics: [(1, [23]), (3, [23]), (4, [23]), (5, [23]), (6, [23]), (7, [23])]
Word phis: [(1, [(23, 1.0)]), (3, [(23, 1.0)]), (4, [(23, 1.0)]), (5, [(23, 1.0)]), (6, [(23, 1.0)]), (7, [(23, 1.0)])]
--------------
new doc
Document topics: [(28, 0.80199999993851401)]
Word topics: [(0, [28]), (6, [28]), (7, [28]), (8, [28])]
Word phis: [(0, [(28, 1.0)]), (6, [(28, 1.0)]), (7, [(28, 1.0000000000000002)]), (8, [(28, 1.0)])]
--------------
```

Can anyone please help converting this function to be more optimized and as fast as possible (and generate the same output)?? It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How fast is it?  How fast does it need to be?

Comment: @DietrichEpp This code should give the result for corpus with entries as big as 1 GB. So, the helper function should be really fast. The above function isn't that efficient.

Comment: How do you know it isn't efficient? It does not seem you can get more efficient than len(topics) * max_len( doc_topics, word_topics, word_phis)

Comment: @ParthoMandal: How fast is "really fast"? 1 GB is still pretty small, but you might run into problems with memory usage due to object overhead.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am creating dict, storing values in dict then again iterating through all values to store it as tuples in list. I want to directly store the list of tuples using the topics mentioned above. Isn't there any better way to rewrite this code ??

Comment: @DietrichEpp Can the concept of generator and yield be implemented on list of topics to further improve this code to avoid the memory usage overhead?

Comment: Have you identified any hotspots in the above code?

Comment: You could refactor the code because DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), but that doesn't improve efficiency

Comment: @PaulRooney I have to iterate through the list of topics generated. However, the corpus size is really huge. Can some optimization be done through iteration on list of topics?? Each of the topic result is fetched via yield.

Comment: Instead of appending to the list and returning it in the end you may just yield the value.

Comment: I think instead of the last three loops, `doc_topics.extend(document_topics.items())`, etc would suffice, and `word_topics.get(key[0], []).append(key_doc)` allows you to delete the `set_default()`, or `word_topics = default_dict(list))`, delete `set_default` and keep `word_topics[key[0]].append(key_doc)`. The `for` loops would also be faster, perhaps, with list comprehensions.

Comment: You can shave maybe 10% off by writing `word_topics.setdefault(key, []).append(...)` as opposed to what you have. Also, the last three `for`-loops are just doing `document_topics.items()`, aren't they? You might try re-implementing with numba, but that would take some work, and I can't say what type of speed-up to expect.

Comment: Also in your last 3 loops. You needlessly unpack and repack tuples. You could convert these loops into comprehensions , keeping the tuples returned from `iteritems` and stuffing them straight into the list. e.g. `doc_topics = (i for i in document_topics.iteritems())`. The tuple manipulation is removed and the comprehension is probably executed much quicker in c code than a manual loop in interpreted python bytecodes.